# How do I get Tkinter Entry.get() to equal 0 if theres no entry?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im writing a restaraunt management program in tkinter and I have the menu listed out. if I don't put anything in the entry box it will say error. How do I make it that when the entry box is empty, it is equal to 0?

Comment: You have to make a Minimal Reproducible Example (see the StackOverflow Help Center for more details), because without seeing any code at all, we cannot tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a value like this:

```
value = entry.get() or 0
```

If the entry widget has nothing in it, it will return an empty string. An empty string is treated as False in an expression. Because it is False, the part after the `or` will be returned.